# React native customizing progress bar

Tags: react-native

How can I customize and create progress bar like that in react native?
Need triangle at the bottom which indicates the current value, and the points with values at the bottom with possible bounds.

[image: custom progress bar]

Comment: What is exactly your problem ?
Do you need to know how to make a triangle ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl want to understand how react standard progress bar component can be customized like on that image?

Comment: Please ask a concrete question and don't ask others to code for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @gothica. please show what you have done so far and what is your problem exactly. Also, it's not clear whether your question is about implementing the component in React or React-Native. be more accurate and remove the unrelated tag from your question.

Comment: @MichaelBahl
         <ProgressBar
          style={styles.ProgressBar}
          progress={2 * 0.083}
          color={'#5e5e5e'}
        /> 
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   ProgressBar: {
    height: 14,
    borderRadius: 100,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  }
});

I want also to add triangle at the top of bar and points with values at the bottom..

Comment: @SaeedZhiany, please see my comment above.

Comment: btw, i'm trying to customize ProgressBar component from react native paper. [link]( https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/ProgressBar/) but can't figure out how to finally do the same look as the topic image

Comment: @gothica I'm not sure React-Native-Paper has the options you want and you need to write your component from scratch. you can use [this link](https://www.skptricks.com/2018/11/how-to-create-custom-triangle-shape-in-react-native.html) to learn how to create a triangle, and use styles like `position: absolute` + `left, right, top, bottom`, to place the dot labels in the desired places.